# How can I trigger other job after changes on specific branch?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

currently I have jobs:

- Build&Test - this build project and runs unit/integration tests for all branches.
- Test Deploy - this should automatically deploy to test server from testServer branch
- Prod Deploy - this should deploy to Prod Server after manual trigger (merging changes from testServer)

I've tired using Build Pipeline plugin for this, but Test Deploy plan is run always when Build&Test plan succeed and I only want it to run if testServer branch was build. In Test Deploy plan I've configured git to checkout only testServer but task is run even if there were no changes on testServer branch.

Answer (score 0):

The one way i can think of
1, Run the Build&Test job.
2, Pass the branch parameter from "build&test" to "test deploy" job as parameterized build only if build&test job passed.
3, Read the Branch parameter during "test deploy" execution, If branch is "testServer" then go ahead with actual deploy+test steps in the job otherwise exit without doing anything.

Comment: how I can check in job which branch is being build?
Currently I got it working by using regexp to checkout branches and creating
"Test Deploy" - checkout testServer build project run tests deploy application
"Build Commons" - checkout buildCommons build commons artifact and push it to nexus repository 
"Build Client" - checkout buildClient build client, run tests, build artifact and push it to nexus repository 
"Build&Test" - checkout other branches using regexp I can put it here tomorrow, because now I'm at home
I also needed to use Exclusion-Plugin because integration tests use the same DB

Comment: here is branch specifier ":^(?!.*master|.*testServer|.*nexusClient|.*nexusCommons).*$" maybe it will help someone. It checkout every other branch than those mentioned